# Android Studio Error:Wrong committed revision number: -1

Tags: android, svn, android-studio, tortoisesvn

I have suddenly huge SVN problems with Android Studio.

I´m getting

> Error:Wrong committed revision number: -1

every commit attempt. Using Tortoise works fine.

It occures on fresh projects and also fresh checked out projects which were committed by Tortoise before

How can I solve this problem??

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a project that I built from scratch over some time and always commited to a subversion repository as a sole user. After I did a fresh check out of this project on another computer during the holidays, I got this error. When I returned home, I tried it on my computer by deleting the existing project and checking it out again, unfortunately resulting in the same error.

As I had made a backup copy before deleting, I compared both project directories and it I saw, that they had a different subversion working copy format. Then I checked out again and choose "1.6 format" as the working copy format and the error was gone.

My server is a 1.6 server, but as it is compatible with 1.8 clients, I thought, the working copy format shouldn't matter. BTW, I had the impression, that even though I got this error, the changes were in fact committed, so maybe it's a problem of Android Studio's svn client.

Answer (score 0):

The svn command line client returns unparseable output to Android Studio (IntelliJ) if the locale is other then english. So for me the following works fine:

create a shellscript, eg. name it /usr/local/bin/svn-en with the following content:

```
export LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
svn $@
```

Then in Android Studio goto Project Settings -> Version Control -> Subversion.
In the tab "General" enter in the "use command line client" field: /usr/local/bin/svn-en

Comment: above works for linux environment. Maybe for windows and osx there are similiar solutions.